# trying to divide negatives and positives in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Very new, trying to make a function that takes out and separates all negatives/positives/zeros in an array. So far Ive been able to make an acceptable for loop but only with hard coded numbers. Dont currently know how to convert it into a function. please help.

```
var arr=[1,3,5,-9,-3,0];
var new_arr = [];
var new_arr2 = [];
var new_arr3=[];
for(i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]>0){
      new_arr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else if(arr[i]<0){
      new_arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else if(arr[i]===0){
      new_arr3.push(arr[i]);
    }  
}
console.log(new_arr3.length/arr.length);
console.log(new_arr2.length/arr.length);
console.log(new_arr.length/arr.length);
```

Comment: The ultimate goal is to take the total amount of indexes in the new arrays and divide them by the number of indexes in the original array.

Comment: If you are interested in the count of those numbers then why don't you use simple number variables as counters instead of creating a new array for each type. `var counterNeg = 0, counterPos = 0, counterZero = 0;` and then increment them like: `if(arr[i] < 0) { counterNeg++; }`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```js
function division(arr) {
  var new_arr = [];
  var new_arr2 = [];
  var new_arr3 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      new_arr.push(arr[i]);
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      new_arr2.push(arr[i]);
    } else if (arr[i] === 0) {
      new_arr3.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(new_arr3.length / arr.length);
  console.log(new_arr2.length / arr.length);
  console.log(new_arr.length / arr.length);
}

division([1, 3, 5, -9, -3, 0]);
```

This new function takes the array as a parameter, so all you need to do is call it and pass the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also, here I am considering `0` as a positive number. If you want, you can tweak the condition as per requirement.

```
  function positive_negative(array ){

    positive = array.filter(function (a) { return a >= 0; });
    negative = array.filter(function (a) { return a < 0; });
    return [positive,negative];

  }

var array = [1,3,5,-9,-3,0];
console.log(positive_negative(array));
```